# Programmatically check if an Angular ng-content slot has been provided

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have created an expandable Angular component that uses content projection and slots like this:

```html
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="short-wrapper" [style.opacity]="expanded ? 0 : 1">
        <ng-content select="[short]"></ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="full-wrapper" [style.opacity]="expanded ? 1 : 0">
        <ng-content select="[full]"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
```

...to choose between the content shown for the contracted (short) and expanded (full) form of the component.

Each component has an icon as well. What I'd like to do is detect whether or not the `[short]` content has been specified, and, if not, use an enlarged version of the icon as the contracted-state content of the component.

I have no idea how, however, *in the Typescript code* for my component, to detect if the `[short]` content is present or not. If the `[short]` content is missing, I'd like to programmatically change the CSS class of the icon so it changes from a small upper-left icon to a larger centered icon, filling the space where the short content otherwise would have gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but this solution works:

First, I added the name `#short` to the following `div`.

```
      <div class="short-wrapper" #short [style.opacity]="expanded ? 0 : 1">
        <ng-content select="[short]"></ng-content>
      </div>
```

Then I defined it as a `ViewChild`.

```
 @ViewChild('short', { static: true }) shortRef: ElementRef;
```

Finally, in the `ngOnInit()` method of my component, I can test if the content of the `short` `div` is empty, which it will be if the `short` slot isn't specified.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if ((this.shortRef.nativeElement.innerHTML ?? '').trim() === '')
      this.useIconForShortContent = true;
  }
```